# crossplatform 64 bit type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc, sizeof, bit

Is there a 64 bit type that in every OS(32/64 bit) and for every compiler has a size of 64?

The same question is also for 32 bit type. (It should be int?)

*The origin of the question is* : I am implementing the system which has 2 kinds of instructions :

1. 32 bit
2. 64 bit

I want to write something like:

```
typedef int instruction32bit;

typedef long long instruction64bit //it is not correct some system have sizeof(long long) = 128
```

Comment: `int` by definition is of different size on different machines/compilers. Usually it comes in size "most convenient" to the processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your code to be truly portable, then you probably want to typedef your own type, and use for example

```
   typedef int32_t instruction32bit;
   typedef int64_t instruction64bit;
```

This will work MOST of the time, but if it doesn't for a particular system/compiler/whatever, you can add do something like this:

```
 #ifdef SOMEDEFINE
   typedef long long int instruction64bit;
   typedef int instruction32bit;
 #else
   typedef int32_t instruction32bit;
   typedef int64_t instruction64bit;
 #endif
```

Of course, for each model of compiler/OS (or group thereof) that doesn't support int32_t and int64_t, you probably will need a special `#ifdef`.

This is exactly what all truly portable code does, because no matter how much you find that "nearly all compilers do X", if you get your code popular enough, there's always someone who wants to compile the code with "Bob's Compiler Project" which doesn't have this feature. Of course, the other thing is to just leat those who use "Bob's compiler" edit the typedef itself, and not accept the "For Bob's compiler, you need this ..." patch that inevitably gets sent your way.

As Carl Norum points out in a comment, the `#ifdef` may be possible to convert to a `#if` in many cases, and then use generic types such as `int` and `long`.

Comment: You should probably replace the `ifdef` with some `#if` and some comparisons of constants. Check an implementation of `stdint.h` out as an example.  There's no reason to define things yourself if you can have it happen automatically.

Comment: Good suggestion. Is __WORDSIZE (that gcc/glibc uses) a standard?

Comment: I don't think so.  newlib just uses preprocessor math, IIRC.

Comment: int32_t and int64_t are standard. I feel that much of this answer is rather paranoid. The exact sized types won't exist when the machine doesn't support them.

Comment: But int32_t assumes that the compiler/C library is "new enough". There are plenty of older compilers about that people still use. If you can require that "this must have a new(ish) compiler", and "it can't run on machines that have other than 32/64 bits" [and they are rather unusual these dasy], then I agree.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for `int64_t` and `int32_t`, or their unsigned friends `uint64_t` and `uint32_t`. Include either [`cinttypes`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cinttypes) or [`cstdint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint).

Answer (score 0):

Use `uint_least32_t` and `uint_least64_t`. The fixed-size types `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` will not exist on systems that don't have the exact sizes they describe.

Comment: Questions asks for exact size types

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - no, it doesn't.

Comment: Ok. I guess I don't understand "size of 64".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - it's not clear what's meant by that. I suspect it's not a hard constraint to **exactly** 64 bits, but an assumption that **all** systems have power-of-two data sizes.

Comment: I suspect "size of 64" means equality.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - "I suspect" is not the same as "the question asks for".

Comment: Well, "a size of 64" only has one meaning. Perhaps the person asking the question meant one thing but wrote another. Only the person asking knows.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - "a size of 64" could mean "a size **of exactly** 64" or it could mean "a size **large enough for** 64 bits". The former is rarely a real requirement.

Comment: And I've just realised that you are the Pete Becker that wrote the TR1 book that I have, so I don't want to get into an argument!  ;-) But size of 64 means one thing only. Size of at least 64 means something else. I would never interpret size of 64 as meaning at least. That seems perverse to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - but you're going to tell me I'm perverse. `<g>`